# Silverlight - Is there a performance difference between C# and VB.net Event Handlers?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, silverlight

Being new to both .NET and Silverlight, I have noticed that many of the tutorials for Silverlight (Tim Heuers Blog, Silverlight TV etc) are in C#. I know that the general difference between VB and C# is usually preference.

However one of the major differences I had noticed was the way C# and VB.NET handle events. Is this just a syntactical difference, or is one or the other **optimized** to handle events better? For example, they both get compiled down to the same Intermediate Language, but is the code that is generated identical? Seeing as Silverlight relies on this heavily, I thought it might be worth consideration.

Considering the expertise on this forum, I was wondering if anyone has done research into this, or performance testing.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a difference in the way the handlers are invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that gets generated may not be identical down to the instruction, but the overall effect is the same. You should not see a performance difference in that area.

VB.NET has two syntaxes for events - `AddHandler`, which is the same as C#'s `+=`, and `Handles`, which is just syntactic sugar for `AddHandler` in a constructor.

Comment: Thanks, this is really what I was interested in. I wasn't sure how identical the IL result was, just that they were compatible.

Comment: The Handles keyword actually creates code for a property setter that adds the event handler to the object/removes it from the previous object.

Answer (score 2):

They both get compiled to IL (or in this case Silverlight bytecode) and should perform exactly the same.  Any differences should be just syntactical.

Comment: Note that there are language features available in some languages that the other languages don't have and thus won't have identical IL. Like C#'s foreach and VB.Net's Select Case (yes it's primarily a switch, but it allows for expressions for each case instead of constants)

Comment: @Corey What, in your opinion, is special about C#’s `foreach`?

Comment: I do withdraw that, after looking into it, turns out VB has it too. I think at one point C# did and VB didn't...

Comment: @Corey Just as an aside, even VB6 did have the `For Each` statement – so VB had it *before* C# had it. VB has adopted some other features of previous C# versions.

Comment: I wish C# would hurry up and get expressions in a switch statement.